# How to color pick UIBarButtonItem tintColor

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor, uibarbuttonitemstyle

How do you color pick right RGBA values for UIBarButtonItem tint color so that when default effects are applied you get the results you were expecting?

My designer handed over to me correct RGBA values that I should apply as a tint color to my navigation bar items, but iOS will apply it's effects on bar button items.

You can see this here:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps in the screenshot

[image]

**EDIT 1:** in my case its showing up the exact color which I am setting

[image]

**EDIT 2:** this will show the color for the RGB value as (0,128,198)

[image]
Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, I figure just now that my question sounds like a that silly, you're right. I don't have any problem with "how to" set an UIColor to an UIBarButtonItem, but instead if you set the exact values iOS will apply a default on that button and you will get somewhat different color.

Comment: What are the RGB values please?

Comment: Exactly! Can't you spot the huge difference between the tint color you see in the color picker and what you actually get in a device?

Comment: you are setting the tintColor.. which is different from the actual backGroundColor property of other controls(e.g. UILabel). If you want specific Colors then you should drawRect instead of using native UIBarButton

Comment: My question is exactly that, I mean how to set the tint color (no drawRect, or whatsoever) and get the color expected?